# Issue running fortinet.fortios in Ansible playbook (bad host file? plugins not installed?)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am getting an error with this playbook and am not sure where to look.  Perhaps something isn't defined right in my host file?  (I'm told the playbook is good)

**YML Playbook**

```
- hosts: fortigates
  collections:
   - fortinet.fortios
  connection: httpapi
  vars:
   vdom: "root"
   ansible_httpapi_use_ssl: yes
   ansible_httpapi_validate_certs: no
   ansible_httpapi_port: 443
  tasks:
  - name: Configure global attributes.
    fortios_system_global:
      vdom:  "{{ vdom }}"
      system_global:
        admintimeout: "23"
        hostname: "FortiGate02"
```

**Host file**

```
[fortigates]
fortigate01 ansible_host=192.168.0.103 ansible_user="admin" ansible_password="password"

[fortigates:vars]
ansible_network_os=fortinet.fortios.fortios
#ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

**Error Output**

> TASK [Configure global attributes.] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'getheaders'
> fatal: [fortigate01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-454799bt3QT/ansible-tmp-1593138436.55-45584-34169098305172/AnsiballZ_fortios_system_global.py", line 102, in \n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-454799bt3QT/ansible-tmp-1593138436.55-45584-34169098305172/AnsiballZ_fortios_system_global.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-454799bt3QT/ansible-tmp-1593138436.55-45584-34169098305172/AnsiballZ_fortios_system_global.py", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.fortinet.fortios.plugins.modules.fortios_system_global', init_globals=None, run_name='**main**', alter_sys=True)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 188, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/modules/fortios_system_global.py", line 2075, in \n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/modules/fortios_system_global.py", line 2043, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/modules/fortios_system_global.py", line 1544, in fortios_system\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/modules/fortios_system_global.py", line 1533, in system_global\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/module_utils/fortios/fortios.py", line 173, in set\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/module_utils/fortios/fortios.py", line 146, in get_mkey\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/module_utils/fortios/fortios.py", line 137, in get_mkeyname\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/module_utils/fortios/fortios.py", line 126, in schema\n  File "/tmp/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload_CQaHFo/ansible_fortios_system_global_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py", line 185, in **rpc**\nansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'getheaders'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

I have installed the Ansible Galaxy package, as per [the documentation](https://galaxy.ansible.com/fortinet/fortios)

```
# ansible-galaxy collection install fortinet.fortios
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Skipping 'fortinet.fortios' as it is already installed
```

Comment: I've changed the format of the error output from `code` to `quotation`. It was very difficult to navigate once line only.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about that. I am new to formatting on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL).

I fixed it by installing ansible with pip3.

```
# remove ansible
sudo apt remove ansible
# install python3 & pip3
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
# install ansible with pip3
pip3 install ansible --user
# update the environment PATH variable for ansible commands
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# install fortios module
ansible-galaxy collection install fortinet.fortios
```

Comment: Thanks, Charles.  This seems to have fixed it!